# Export Jupyter Notebook cell output that includes Plotly plots to an html file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a cell in a pretty long jupyter notebook that has an output that includes text (through print statements) as well as 3D scatter plots made with plotly (a python plotting library). The text and plts are interspersed and that's important because the text explains the plots. Also, these 3D plots are nice because you can pivot them with your cursor and really visualise the data nicely (see what I mean [here](https://plotly.com/python/3d-scatter-plots/)).

I want to export this output as an html (or other format) that would look the same as the cell output within Jupyter. That means, ideally, the plots would still be able to pivot with the cursor.

I've tried using the `%%capture` magic but it throws an error when I try to save it to html. I tried it with a cell that just has text outputs and it worked fine, so I assume it's the plots that made it not work.

Does anyone have a solution for how to export this output? All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!